# Can IntelliJ create hyperlinks to the source code from log4j output?

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j, intellij-idea

In the IntelliJ console, stack traces automatically contain hyperlinks that bring you to the relevant source files.  The links appear at the end of each line in the format (Log4jLoggerTest.java:25).  I can configure log4j to output text in a similar format.

```
log4j.appender.Console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

In eclipse, the console automatically turned text like this into links.  In IntelliJ, the stack traces are links but my own output in the same form remains un-linked.  Is there any way to get IntelliJ to do the same?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can, try this pattern:

```
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p - [%-80m] - at %c.%M(%F:%L)%n"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works.  The relevant part of the pattern seems to be the entire string "at %c.%M(%F:%L)"

Comment: I just tried this with intellij 12.0.4 and it doesn't seem to work, would be a great feature though

Comment: scratch that previous comment, I simply forgot to compile my code with debug info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937485/line-number-not-showing

Comment: The relevant part of the pattern seems to be `\(%F:%L\)`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA to get clickable links in your console called [Awesome Console](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7677).

Answer (score 2):

FYI, in logback and Intellij 13 this worked for me:

```
<pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy} %d{HH:mm:ss} %p %m - at %C.%M\(%F:%L\)%n</pattern>
```

Note:  I needed the "at" and I also needed to escape the parentheses.  Also capital "C" is the fully qualified classname in logback.

With this config I get output like:

```
10-06-2014 10:10:58 INFO Bean 'mbeanServer' of type [class com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying) - at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1374)
```

And the final part in parentheses shows up as a link in Intellij.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way. But I think I submitted this as a feature request a long time ago. Maybe you should do the same. Jetbrains does listen to its customers. But it can take ages before they implement things like this.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{MM-dd HH:mm:ss}]%5p %l %m%n
```