# Line number not showing?

Tags: java, log4j

I have discovered some issues in my program.
I was using log4j for logging,
however, inside the log file, all line number become "?".

The conversation pattern is as follow:

```
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %c: %L - %m%n
```

Comment: IIRC you need to compile with debugging symbols or else that information is stripped from the `.class` files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are most probably missing debug information in your compiled artifacts.
I.e. it is not log4j's fault, you need to make sure you are compiling your stuff with debug information included.
A quick test would be to try and debug your app with your favourite IDE.
If there is no debug info it will complain and won't establish debug session...

Comment: as above. It would be useful if you can tell us how you're compiling the code (ant etc)

Comment: Indeed, I am just stating the most common reason this to happen...Plus I only noticed your comment after I posted my answer :)

Comment: I was using Ant for compiling.

Comment: This is almost certainly the right answer. For example, if compiling with Ant, use `<javac debug='true' ... />`

Answer (score 4):

Set the options `debug="true" debuglevel="lines,source"` in your javac ant-task.

Answer (score 2):

Check once.
i am using your pattern i my code,
and it works better....this is a `log4j.properties` file.

```
  log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG

  # AdminFileAppender - used to log messages in the admin.log file.
  log4j.appender.AdminFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
  log4j.appender.AdminFileAppender.File=admin.log
  log4j.appender.AdminFileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
  log4j.appender.ReportFileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %c: %L - %m%n
  #log4j.appender.AdminFileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%L - %r  %-5p %c %x - %m - %d - %t%n

  # ReportFileAppender - used to log messages in the report.log file.
  log4j.appender.ReportFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
  log4j.appender.ReportFileAppender.File=report.log
  log4j.appender.ReportFileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
  log4j.appender.ReportFileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %c: %L - %m%n
  #log4j.appender.ReportFileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%L  - %r  %-5p %c %x - %m - %d- %t%n

  log4j.logger.com.vaannila.admin=,AdminFileAppender 
  log4j.logger.com.vaannila.report=,ReportFileAppender
```