# Why I have question instead line number when logging with log4j

Tags: groovy, log4j

I try to configure logger to write line number but instead of it I have question.

```
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t]:%L - %m%n
```

I figured out that it is not log4j problem but setting of my project. The most probably missing debug information in my compiled artifacts. ([Line number not showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937485/line-number-not-showing)) But how can I set that in IntellijIdea 2019.1?

Comment: add `%c` into the conversion pattern and show the result

Comment: If I add %c then I have the name of logger in log file

Comment: sorry i mean `%C` (upper) to have classname where event is comming from

Comment: then i have ```org.apache.commons.logging.Log$info```

Comment: That's the problem. Log4j couldn't detect correctly where message is coming from. And again - the same problem discussed for logback. I don't know if log4j has similar config. But definitely problem not in project. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59491564/logback-doesnt-print-method-or-line-number/59504563#59504563

Comment: So sad(  But where I can find logback.groovy?

Comment: it's a first file in answer. and the modified one - at the end