# JetBrains IDE - Clickable links to local files in consol print messages

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

When coding in Python and executing this line of code:

```
print("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

[image]

It is shown in the running console as a pretty nice link =).

But how can I archive that with a local path?

What is not working is:

```
print("file:///C:\Programs\something")
print("C:\Programs\something")
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can IntelliJ create hyperlinks to the source code from log4j output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458820/can-intellij-create-hyperlinks-to-the-source-code-from-log4j-output)

Comment: @TheMisir Are am I right, that this modifies the console it self and it provides the path of the file where the output comes from? - If not I didn't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gotta convert those backslashes to forward slashes:

```
print("file:///C:\Programs\something".replace('\\', '/'))
```